# Need advice for mySQL query for my problem

Tags: php, sql

[I need help for advice query sql to display in php like in picture shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TH4KZ.png)

I need to display data sql,with loop process php, so data can display by turns, (promote- not promote - promote - not promote...)

example

Table A

```
id  brand promote
-----------------
1   A     no
2   B     yes
3   C     yes
4   D     no
5   E     yes
6   f     no
7   G     no
```

Expecting data to display like this,

```
brand promote
-------------
B     yes
C     yes
A     no
D     no
E     yes
F     no
G     no
```

Comment: What have you tried (as in typed) so far?

Comment: StackOverflow accepts exact questions, not drawings. Please edit your question and describe your problem best you can, otherwise it will be downvoted and deleted.

Comment: That's better, thank you. Soon I'll write an answer

Answer (score 0):

MySQL sorts columns by it's values so in your case you can only `order by brand asc` or `order by brand desc` to get `A` to `N` asc order and `N` to `A` desc. The same you can do with your second column,  then you'll have it in `no` to `yes` in asc sorting and reverse sorting with desc.

If you want to sort items in other *random* way you need to add new column, let's name it `sortingcol` of the `integer` type and in it you need to store position you want to give to each item. In case of your... drawing, the values would be

```
brand promote sortingcol
------------------------
B     yes     1
C     yes     2
A     no      3
D     no      4
E     yes     5
F     no      6
G     no      7
```

So then you can just query it like

```
select * from yourtable order by sortingcol asc
```

or

```
select * from yourtable order by sortingcol desc
```

Comment: thank you sir for your answer but the problem is i still cannot make this work, i cannot making loop so the output is  the first 2 rows promote, after then 4 rows not promote,2 promotes again..and soon the pattern...any idea how this can be work..i am sorry, iam trying many loop with many conditional statement but cannot work properly as i expected

Comment: @PaundriSetyoW as I said the only possibility is creating an additional column for sorting, believe me, I'm doing it for 20 years. Other way is sorting it in PHP's array by manual sorting of the brands by key (if they are absolutely unique) however trust me, it will be much slower and much harder to maintenance.

Comment: can you please explain me more detail sir, how to make it work with additional column for sorting (step by step(,..i am sorry my logical thinking is burn out to solve this..

Comment: Actually I described it in my answer. The point is that the additional sorting column will be faster and more comfortable. If you'll implement this you will not need to do anything at PHP's side except of executing simple SQL query and then rendering the output.